# Does RubyMine 2.0 earn its $99 as a Rails IDE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, rubymine

I've seen a lot of blogs talk about RubyMine lately, as a best of breed Rails IDE. Currently, I am using NetBeans IDE for my Ruby and Rails stuff, but I was wondering if anyone here would personally recommend this IDE, and reasons why I should fork out $99 for it.

Comment: They have a free trial -- why not check it out for yourself? Link: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/

Comment: Well worth it for autocomplete and model dependency diagramming alone

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I used NetBeans for a while, before switching to RubyMine some month ago prior the first release.
I can say the IDE is worth the entire price.

RubyMine has the best autocomplete support I have ever seen. It's a really clever IDE, it can understand most of the Rails "magics" including method references by symbols

```
class Controller

  before_filter :mymethod

  def mymethod
  end
end
```

metaprogramming, Rails/Ruby convention and so on.

Also, RubyMine 2.0 introduced i18n support for Rails and, having to maintain a couple of Rails apps localized in 5 different languages, I must say this is an awesome feature.

It supports the latest testing frameworks in the Ruby ecosystem, including Shoulda, Test::Unit, RSpec and Cucumber. Unfortunately it lacks RCov support, while I know Netbeans is going to integrate it.

A couple of co-workers are still using NetBeans and they often have problem with SVN because Netbeans doesn't auto-refresh the working copy when you update it outside the IDE.
RubyMine has an excellent SCM support and ships with SVN, CVS and even Git compatibility.

I don't want this answer to seems like a RubyMine promo, so I encourage you to give it a try for 30days then make a choice.

Comment: Rubymine 2.5 has RCov support, it's available as an Early Release version: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP

Comment: Great ide, I now use Pycharm, RubyMine, Idea and Resharper and at the risk of appearing a fanboy, I can say I have never regretted using any of these as they always do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried Netbean, RadRails and RubyMine. In my personal opinion it's well worth the money, and I heartily agree with weppos.

Your best bet it to try the evaluation version for a while and make your own mind up. I find IDE preferences are very subjective, the only real way to know if it's any good is to try it for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

it is a little buggy and a big resource eater but has the better "intellisense", refactoring, and complementary areas support (haml) i ever seen for ruby/rails. it's appearance under mac os x is lame and is much less usable (in terms of UI usability) than any other ide. i guess that in the next major versions it will become the ruby/rails killer-ide. i would wait to buy it, as i see it as an immature project right now.

Answer (score 3):

Suffice to say that Rubymine (2.5 EAP version) is the first IDE I actually like. Having used
to excellence of developing Rails apps in OS X with TexMate, when I switched the job and was forced to get along without OS X, I was quite satisfied to find Rubymine.

A veteran Emacs user (over 10 years) and recent Vim convert (gotta love the extremely powerful command system and short key bindings), I soon found that either the file navigation, cucumber editing or refactoring support was quite lacking in those. With Rubymine, I get TextMate-style file navigation which is just awesome, the only IDE which actually has a type inferencing engine and is able to capture many run-time errors during the editing phase, plus all the features I ever used in Rails projects.

Yes, I'm going to buy the software when they release 3.0 or so, and I don't know if I'll use TextMate in the future when I get again access to OS X. They say the OS X support is very good in Rubymine EAP versions, but what's nice that you can have that for every other OS as well.

Comment: That said, while I still find Rubymine the most appropriate IDE there is, by heart I'm an editor guy, and Sublime Text Editor suffices very well to my needs, providing me this warm, fuzzy feeling that I know everything that happens. With appropriate plugins Sublime offers IDE-like features like check on save, which complains if syntax is not valid Ruby, ability to evaluate expressions etc.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for answering in short. I'll add that debugging via RubyMine is very convenient. Just set a breakpoint and  try to hit the point.  You can see all of your vars, set watches, and investigate objects right in the debug console.

I'd highly recommend it to any Ruby developer.

Comment: I've moved to RubyMine for other reasons, but AFAIK NetBeans can also do this now.

Answer (score 3):

To me, there are 3 big advantages in RubyMine that other free or cheap editors/IDE's don't have (notably TextMate and Ruby VIM):

- The **ability to browse all the gem sources**, navigate to the definition of a library method deep in a gem in a single keystroke (CTRL + B on Linux, Cmd + B on Mac), or related docs (CTRL + Q on Linux).
- **Graphical debugger integration**. If you are debugging with print statements and the command line debugger is too cryptic too you (can't see the forest for all the trees), then the time savings alone of debugging a running test suite or live server are worth the price of RubyMine (if you value your time at all).
- The continued dedication of the JetBrains team to **keep up and integrate with** all the whims and trends of the **open source tool chain**. In the 3 years, I've used RubyMine exclusively, I've seen them follow and integrate with every thing that's gaining traction. Their responsiveness is unmatched. Just 3 examples of this: Native cucumber specs in 2009, RVM in 2010, CoffeeScript in 2011.

Comment: +1 for continued dedication of the JetBrains team - and their support was really responsive even when I was in the evaluation period. Add Haml, scss, git, etc support

Answer (score 2):

I use it, and as of right now, don't think it's quite worth it - if you like working with a full IDE, RadRails is as good (though in different ways), and free. I admit, I haven't got all the keyboard shortcuts in RubyMine down, so I'm not as productive with it as I hope to be, but I find myself doing stuff at the command line more than I think should be necessary with a 'real' IDE. It's been pretty stable for me (on linux), the source control integration is good, and it's not as slow as it used to be (though I still end up in vim at times, if I don't want to load it). I'm hoping a 'plugin' ecology will develop around it. Overall, it's a pretty good product, but not (yet?) worth the $99 over RadRails (haven't used NetBeans)

Comment: Also, if you're on Linux, RadRails looks way better than RubyMine and NetBeans, since it's not using Swing.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Netbeans for a while(1+ year) now. and have tried RadRails too. but i choose RubyMine cause:

- the base IDE is very solid and has a
  ton of plugins
- it's generally more intelligent and have good refactoring abilities.
- it supports a good number of other frameworks and technologies outside ruby and rails (like      SaaS, haml, cucumber, shouldr, rspec...etc).
- it supports my favorite version control system: git.

all in all i think if you take some time to learn its key mappings, you can be very productive with it. you wouldn't need to use a shell at all(well sometimes you might need to but...you get the idea).

just my 2 cents

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Rubymine to develop Rails apps for a while now. 
There was a point a few months ago when I would have been hesitant to recommend paying for it.
However the rate at which it has been improving and adding new features is really impressive.
If you're doing BDD (with Cucumber) then it's worth buying just for the step completion and navigation. 
Also the features that have come from IntelliJ like Javascript, HTML, CSS, VCS support etc are excellent.

Answer (score 2):

I am a former NetBeans user.  I LOVE RubyMine!  It has excellent rvm, git, Rspec and cucumber integration, all of which are in my stack.  Go with it.  You won't be sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I used both Redmine and Textmate but I tend to spend more time coding in textmate. It's a matter of preference whatever gets the job done quicker is the best tool in my opinion.

Good Luck @johnrlive

Answer (score 1):

I love how "project aware" RubyMine is. Coming from ST2 (which is still use daily), it's hard not to miss the elegance of an editor like ST2 but working on large scale projects with versioning, RubyMine is the IDE of choice for me. I just wish the would improve the editor and UI.

Answer (score 0):

I just started to explore the IDE concept, being a happy TextMate programmer until just a couple days ago. But now that I've played with both NetBeans and RubyMine, I gotta say RubyMine rocks. NetBeans is cool for the price, but it's slow, slow, slow. Sometimes windows will lock up for long periods of time while something is apparently "thinking" - of what, I can't imagine. On the other hand, even as a fairly novice Ruby programmer, I was able to get RubyMine conversing with Git and AutoTest within a few minutes -- in short I got up and running and back to programming pretty quickly. On the flip side, I still haven't figured out how to get it to work with Heroku or Growl, but I'm still pretty new at it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say depends on what your looking for. Netbeans is definitely a very capable and sufficient IDE. Rubymine shines in its autocompletion and really easy Git integration. If you have a lot of money to spare I would say ruby mine is the way to go. However, in my case, as I am a broke college student Netbeans and/or text mate does the job fine. Spending an additional minute on git outside of netbeans and using my extra monitor for documentation has worked well for me thus far.